# Derived fields in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008 (or it might be 2012), I have an 'activity' table with UserID, Date and Action fields and I want to count the number of times each user performed each action during each day. Unfortunately, 'Action' is just a text field and sometimes it contains more than just the basic action. So I wan something like this:

```
SELECT UserID,
       Cast([Timestamp] AS DATE)                         AS DateField,
       Count(Action LIKE '%Logged In%')                  AS LoggedIn,
       Count(Action LIKE '%Requested Planning Data%')    AS Planning,
       Count(Action LIKE '%Requested Time Series Data%') AS TimeSeries,
       Count(Action LIKE '%Requested Analytical Data%')  AS Analytical
FROM   Activity
ORDER  BY UserID,
          DateField
```

The results should look something like this:

```
UserID  DateField   LoggedIn  Planning  TimeSeries  Analytical
------  ---------   --------  --------  ----------  ----------
1       01-11-2014  1         1         0           2
1       02-11-2014  3         7         2           5
2       01-11-2014  1         8         0           0
...
```

But I have no idea how to derive the 'count' columns. Is this even possible? The raw table looks something like this:

```
UserID  Timestamp            Action
1       01-11-2014 09:00:15  User Logged In
1       01-11-2014 09:01:15  User Requested Planning Data for 2 sites
1       01-11-2014 09:07:15  User Requested Analytical Data for 1 sites
1       01-11-2014 09:25:15  User Requested Analytical Data for 8 sites
1       02-11-2014 09:03:15  User Logged In
1       02-11-2014 09:07:15  User Logged In
...
```

--- Alistair

Comment: Even though your problem already has a good answer, I am wondering... What data type is `Timestamp`?

Comment: Fun tip: you can see your installed version by run `SELECT @@VERSION` in a query.  It will return a single-value result that tells you the version details of your server.

Comment: Andrew, Timestamp is a DateTime. I am casting it to a Date in order to remove the time portion so I can group by Day.
AHiggins, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `conditional aggregate`. Try this.

```
SELECT UserID, CAST([Timestamp] AS date) AS DateField,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN Action LIKE '%Logged In%' THEN 1 END) 
       AS LoggedIn,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN Action LIKE '%Requested Planning Data%' THEN 1 END) 
       AS Planning,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN Action LIKE '%Requested Time Series Data%' THEN 1 END) 
       AS TimeSeries,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN Action LIKE '%Requested Analytical Data%' THEN 1 END) 
       AS Analytical
FROM Activity
ORDER BY UserID, CAST([Timestamp] AS date)
```

Comment: You could simplify this solution a bit if you use this syntax: `COUNT(CASE WHEN Action LIKE '%Logged In%' THEN 1 END) AS LoggedIn`

Comment: @Andrew - Thank you. Simplified